# how to compute $\int {\ln^2 {(1+x^2)}}\, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I want to solve the following IVP :

\begin{cases}
u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0 \; & \text{in} \; \mathbb{R} \times(0,+\infty) \\
u = \cos ^2 x, \; u_t = \ln^2 {(1+x^2)} \; & \text{on} \;  \mathbb{R} \times\{t = 0\}
\end{cases}

if I use D'Alembert's formula I'll have to find a primitive of $\ln^2 {(1+x^2)}$

which I tried computing using an integration by parts, so firstly I had to find $\int \ln (1+x^2)\, dx = x \ln (1+x^2) +2(\arctan x - x )$ and then I got stuck in on the integrals that's appeared which is $\int \frac{x \arctan x}{1+x^2}\, dx$ which by means of a u-substitution I could reduce to $\int u \tan u \, du$ but I couldn't go further.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you need to evaluate that integral? It looks to be like your antiderivative is finished.

Comment: @J.G. so you're saying some terms should vanish, all right I'll compute again.

Comment: You need to understand that expressing your answer in terms of integrals is considered a solution, without having to find closed forms for them. A large number of functions expressible in terms of simple functions do not have antiderivatives that are similarly expressible. So chasing after them always is a fool's errand.